# nservicebus, Server to send back message to distributor?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

I am using nservicebus 1.9 version in my project. My project we are using publisher- subscriber model. Like publisher will send messages to Distributor and Distributor will forward the same message to one of the subscribed Subscribers. 
 but in my project subscriber will do some operation and inserts the data into database,

My requirement is if subscribers fails to insert data into the database i need send it backi to distributor. How can I do that one? Can subscriber send Messages back to distributor?

nRk

Answer (score 1):

When a node receives a message from a distributor, that message doesn't return to the distributor in case of failure, it is moved to the configured error queue. Now, you could set the error queue to be the data queue of the distributor, but that could leave garbage in your system which clogs up the pipes. In short, you want to get the garbage out so that an administrator can look at it and decide what to do - return it to the distributor or do something else.

Does that answer your question?